# how to delete blob element from a table in sqlite android?

Tags: android

I am sending bytearray to insert an blob element it is inserting as png image it is working.But i want to delete blob element for these i am sending bytearray to column but it not deleting.

```
public void deleteImage(Byte[] bytearray)
 {
  try{
   database.execSQL("DELETE FROM deleteImage "+" where image='"+bytearray+"';");
  }
  catch(Exception e){
   e.toString();
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Comparing blobs its time expensive it would be better to introduce index or checksum and check those.

```
When two BLOB values are compared, the result is determined using memcmp().
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the id of image and  delete the row

```
sqLiteDatabase.delete(TABLE_NAME, "_id=" + id, null);
```

If u want to update another image then do the update operation.

```
 String strFilter = "_id=" + idOfDbRow;
 ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
 cv.put("blob", blobfile);
 sqLiteDatabase.update(TABLE_NAME, cv, strFilter, null);
```